# Upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04, 16.04

I am highly looking forward to the new flavor of Ubuntu and it's bells and whistles to wrap the bow on top. My only concern is upgrading to it from my current system without reinstalling Ubuntu entirely. I have seen it discussed, and attempted, and know how horrible the results typically are. I recently read an article in respect to some lead developer saying that if it was to be done, it would most likely upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 then to 16.04. It was a credible sources, otherwise I wouldn't mention it I lost the link unfortunately in my research. 
So anyway, what do you guys think? Will there be a direct upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04, or will you have to go to 15.04 to get to 16.04? And if you DO have to upgrade to 15.04 instead of streamlining it to 16.04, is it even worth doing at that point? Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: You must have misunderstood something, because upgrading from 14.04 to 15.04 is not supported, and upgrading from 15.04 to 16.04 will probably nor be supported either.

Comment: yes, you can. Just set in update manager settings (notify me of a new Ubintu version: for long-term support versions) and run `update-manager -d` in terminal

Comment: @avtomaton - How do I do that on ubuntu server (e.g. without a display manager at all).

Comment: Tried `update-manager -d`. Broke the UI.

Comment: I still have not been offered an update.  I tried following the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenialUpgrades, but it only offered to update to 15.10, not 16.04.  Apparently, nobody knows what's going on, which is probably why all the answers are always different.