# How to update xubuntu 14.04 LTS to xubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: updates, xubuntu

How to upgrade xubuntu 14.04 LTS to xubuntu 16.04? I don't want to lose my application data.

Comment: please read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/729522/upgrading-from-14-04-lts-to-16-04-lts

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: The `-d` option is to upgrade to the next development release. This is not what the OP is asking for.