# How to Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 gnome to Ubuntu 16.04 gnome

Tags: 14.04, gnome, upgrade, 16.04

I dont want to mess any thing ,hence asking the question for clarification .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To check if upgrading to the latest development release is possible:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), and type:

> update-manager -d

If available run following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type in `update-manager`, then the **Software Updater** should provide you a notification for newly available Ubuntu 16.04. Click on **Upgrade** and proceed with the installation.

Since you do not want to mess anything you should consider doing a fresh install because  16.04 has many significant changes compared to 14.04, e.g. it supports *ZFS filesystem*. Also there are many deep rooted packages in 14.04 which might create difficulty during the upgrade.

You may like to have a walk through following links:

[Can I smoothly upgrade from one LTS to next LTS release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release)

[Upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729522/upgrading-from-14-04-lts-to-16-04-lts)